# pass value through <a href="#myModel" ></a> tag (pass data value value using link in html)?

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel-5

I use a href to call same page dialog box id.

this is my part of code

```
                  <tbody>                  

                        @foreach ($basl_officers as $basl_officer)
                        <tr >
                            <td><a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> {{ $basl_officer->code }} </a></td>        

                            <td align='center'>
                                {!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route'=>['basl_officers_page.destroy',$basl_officer->id]]) !!}
                                <a href="{{route('basl_officers_page.edit',$basl_officer->id)}}" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> </a> &nbsp &nbsp
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> </button> 
                                {!! Form::close() !!}
                            </td> 
                        </tr>


                        @endforeach

                    </tbody>
```

//Model dialogue box code

```
 <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog"> 
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style='float: right;' data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span></button>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" style='float: right;'> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> </a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" style='float: right;'> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> </a>
                <h4 class="modal-title">BASL  Officers  Details {{ $basl_officer }} </h4>
            </div>



            <!-- text input -->
            <div class="modal-body">

                {!! Form::label('o_code', 'Officers Code: '); !!}
                {!! Form::text('officers_code', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'officers_code','disabled' => 'disabled']); !!}


                {!! Form::label('o_name', 'Officers Name: '); !!}
                {!! Form::text('officers_name', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'officers_name','disabled' => 'disabled']); !!}


            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I want to pass select table row , $basl_officer object to this #myModal dialogue.is there any way to do this? please expect some expert help as soon as possible. since one week I try to do this different way .I use Laravel 5 framework.

///////////////////full code///////////////////////////////////////////////

```
    @extends('layouts.app')

@section('slide_bar')
@include('layouts.master_entry_slide_bar')
@endsection

@section('content')




<section class="content-header">
    <h1>BASL  Officers  <small>page </small></h1>
</section>


<br/>

<!-- Main content -->
<section class="content fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="gap">
                <div class="box-body">
                    <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                        <col width='auto'>
                        <col width='auto'>
                        <col width='100'>

                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>BASL Officers Code</th>
                                <th>BASL Officers Name</th>
                                <th><p id='buttons'> <a href="{{ route('basl_officers_page.create')}}" class="btn btn-success"> <strong> Add New Officers &nbsp </strong> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> </a> </p></th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>                  

                            @foreach ($basl_officers as $basl_officer)
                            <tr >
                                <td><a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">  {{ $basl_officer->code }} </a></td>        
                                <td><a href="#" >{{ $basl_officer->officerName }} </a></td>        
                                <td align='center'>
                                    {!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route'=>['basl_officers_page.destroy',$basl_officer->id]]) !!}
                                    <a href="{{route('basl_officers_page.edit',$basl_officer->id)}}" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> </a> &nbsp &nbsp
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> </button> 
                                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                                </td> 
                            </tr>
                            @endforeach

                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <th>BASL Officers Code</th>
                                <th>BASL Officers Name</th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
                </div><!-- /.box-body -->
            </div><!-- /.box -->
        </div>

    </div><!-- /.row -->

</section><!-- /.content -->

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog"> 
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style='float: right;' data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span></button>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" style='float: right;'> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> </a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" style='float: right;'> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> </a>
                <h4 class="modal-title">BASL  Officers  Details {{ $basl_officer }} </h4>

            </div>



            <!-- text input -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>

                {!! Form::label('o_code', 'Officers Code: '); !!}
                {!! Form::text('officers_code', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'officers_code','disabled' => 'disabled']); !!}


                {!! Form::label('o_name', 'Officers Name: '); !!}
                {!! Form::text('officers_name', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'officers_name','disabled' => 'disabled']); !!}


            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>


<script>
            var name = document.getElementById("master_entry");
            document.getElementById("master_entry").className = "active";
            var slide_bar_element = document.getElementById("bd_menu");
            document.getElementById("bd_menu").className = "active";
            var slide_bar_element = document.getElementById("bd_submenu1");
            document.getElementById("bd_submenu1").className = "active";

</script>



<script>            
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
             $('.modal-body').text($(e.relatedTarget).text());
    }
</script>




@endsection
```

I want to show selected table row data value in this dialog box

[image: I want to show selected table row data value in this dialog box]

Comment: some one down vote this question... but i think better down vote give some reason for it . ;-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `bootstrap-modal`'s `shown.bs.modal` event and capture the `related target` which triggered the `modal` as below:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  alert($(e.relatedTarget).text());
})
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/c595gnhs/)**

---

**Update**

By seeing your code structure, I can give you one possible solution which is as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var name = document.getElementById("master_entry");
    document.getElementById("master_entry").className = "active";
    var slide_bar_element = document.getElementById("bd_menu");
    document.getElementById("bd_menu").className = "active";
    var slide_bar_element = document.getElementById("bd_submenu1");
    document.getElementById("bd_submenu1").className = "active";

    //modal part
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $('.modal-body #officers_code').val($(e.relatedTarget).text());
        //assign officers code to officers_code textbox
        $('.modal-body #officers_name').val($(e.relatedTarget).closest('td').next().find('a').text())
        //get the relatedTarget elements next anchor element and assign its text to officers_name textbox
    })
</script>
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/c595gnhs/3/)**

Comment: Thank you @Guruprasad, accoding to your solution I write JavaScript an now I can pass click value to that  JavaScript  function. but i want to pass that value #myModal and print it in #myModel. plz , can you give some help?

Comment: @uma .. Something like **[this](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/c595gnhs/1/)**?

Comment: thank you sir exactly i want to do this thing. this code my page  <script>  $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
     $('.modal-body').text($(e.relatedTarget).text());
}) </script> . and modify model body div. but still not result like you. plz, can you tell me how out this code to my page?

Comment: @uma.. Just post the screenshot of how you are getting if possible and also rendered `html` of the `modal` from browser..

Comment: i added my full code ,you do exactly correct thing , plz , I don't know if am i correct to add JavaScript  to my page. so I , put full code. plz , can you help me ? 1000 thousand thanks for you , if you correct this.

Comment: I add your same code and also , same Model class to you put me to show demo. but still not value set to the fields ? :'(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90282/discussion-between-uma-and-guruprasad-rao).